# Setting Java Card Platform Version in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, javacard

I'm new to Java Card Programming. I manage to configure Eclipse IDE with Java Card Platform 3.1 and Eclipse-Plugin. My target Java Card is 3.0.4 compliant (ACS ACOSJ).

As per documentation Java Card Platform 3.1 should allow me to create 3.0.4 compatible applets.

I know I can run converter from command line with -target 3.0.4 parameter.

Now my question is: Where in Eclipse IDE or project properties I can set target platform version to 3.0.4. At the moment when building project it default me to 3.1.